# Convert Javascript Date to ASP.NET Date format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, momentjs

I would like to convert a Javascript date format to ASP.NET date format.

```
2012-09-10 12:00PM to /Date(1347442050050-0700)/
```

Because I'm passing it back to the server. I got the ASP.NET format from the request I did on the server, then convert it to Javascript date using moment.js:

```
moment("/Date(1347442050050-0700)/").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmA");
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want asp => js or js => asp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got what i need. If this is somehow wrong please comment.

```
var test = moment("2012-09-10 12:00PM").valueOf();
var test2 = moment("2012-09-10 12:00PM").format("ZZ");

var test1 = "/Date("+test+test2+")/";

alert( test1 ); // returns /Date(1347206400000+0800)/

var string = moment(test1).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmA");

alert( string );​ // returns 2012-09-10 12:00PM
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `moment('2012-09-10 12:00PM').format('[/Date(]xZZ[))/]')`.

Comment: @Filipe Correia Thanks, very useful for me! But shouldn't it be `'[/Date(]xZZ[)/]'` (1 less parenthesis on the right)?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the function to the moment prototype so that it's a little more portable.

http://jsfiddle.net/timrwood/qe8pk/

```
moment.fn.toASP = function () {
    return '/Date(' + (+this) + this.format('ZZ') + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a date back to an ASP.NET ASMX web service where the RPC method receives a DateTime object, this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973157/1145963